How to encrypt user info in token - OpenIddict
I'm working with OpenIddict and implementing the AuthorizationCodeFlow. I want to encrypt the User Info Token, to return it as JWE (JSON Web Encryption) token to the service provider.
I'm unsure how to configure OpenIddict to issue encrypted userinfo tokens instead of plain JWT tokens in this flow. Could someone provide guidance or example configurations for achieving this?
Specifically,
What settings or key management steps should I follow to generate the JWE format for the token?
I did try sample configurations for encryption and decryption settings from the website, but no luck.
